# ngModel: Get & Set the Value of a Slider from one Function to another Function

Tags: angular, typescript, slider, ngmodel

I am pretty new to Angular but i am trying my best to describe my "problem".

I want to get & set the value of a slider (Angular Material HTML) to a variable in the same component (Typescript/Angular) to change the opacity.

For this i am using the [(ngModel)] + the (input) event in the Material Slider using the MatSliderChange Function. In the console.log i get the Value when sliding + also in an input field with using these: {{}}.

Now i want to pass the value of the slider (opacityslider.value) to another function (Open Street Map Opacity Layer).
But i always get the argument: opacityslider can't be found. I know its inside the function, but here i need your help to find a solution :)

```js
export class OpacityComponent {
  
  public opacityvalue: number = 0.5;

  public opacityStyle(event: MatSliderChange) {
    console.log(event.value);
    return event.value;
   }
  
  constructor() { }
 
  public setupLayer(){
    let openStreetMap = new TileLayer({
      title: 'Open Street Map',
      source: new OSM(),
      opacity: this.opacityStyle(opacityslider.value),
      });
   }
 }
```

```html
<mat-slider id="opacityInput" thumbLabel step="0.1" min="0" max="1" aria-label="units"
  [(ngModel)]="opacityvalue" (input)="opacityStyle($event)">
</mat-slider>
<input value = {{opacityvalue}} />
```

Appreciate any help, regards Chris :)

Comment: `opacityslider` only exist into the function `opacityStyle` -is the argument of the function-
do you want to say `opacityvalue` (the variable you use in the [(ngModel)])?

Comment: Hi Eliseo, thanks for your replay. For your Info: i edited the variable opacityslider to event (according to the HTML input=opacitystyle($event). But even though when i use the variable "opacityvalue" as -- opacity: this.opacityvalue  -- i only get the value of 0.5. But i want it to be dynamic according to the slider :)

Comment: The idea is that the variable change when you make the slice, and you use this variable in your function, [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udxcjn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider-overview-example.ts) is a fool stackblitz

Comment: Hi Eliseo, sorry for the late reply. I am still stucked, even with your example, that i get the value in the console + in the "input" field, but i can't get the value to the "opacity: this.opacityStyle(opacityslider.value)" - here i only get undefined.